# Differential form

Tags: differential-forms

Let $(u^3+A)^{-2}(-\frac{5}{2}u^2-Bu)du \wedge \omega= d\omega$

Where A and B are constant.

I don't know how to calculate $\omega$.

$\omega$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you'd need to find the function $v(u)$ such that
$$
\mathrm{d}(\ln(v)) = \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{v} = \frac{(5u^2+2Bu)\mathrm{d}u}{2(u^3+A)^2}\,,
$$
which is a integral calculus problem.  (It probably doesn't have any particularly nice answer for general constants $A$ and $B$, though.  You could run it through Maple or Mathematica to see what happens.)

Then you'd have $\omega = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{v}$ for some function $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I get involved with another question, but being similar I would not like to open another topic...

If I have: $-(5/2)(u^3+A)^{(-1)}u^2du \wedge w= dw$, How can I calculate $w$ ? Where $A$ is a generic constant

Comment: Well, the best you can do is notice that this equation implies that $\mathrm{d}\bigl( |u^3{+}A|^{5/6}\,w\bigr)=0$, so, if the manifold is simply connected, you'll get that $w = |u^3{+}A|^{-5/6}\,\mathrm{d}v$ for some smooth function $v$.  Of course, I'm assuming that you don't have to worry about the locus where $u^3 =-A$ since the equation you are writing doesn't make sense on that locus.